# ffmpeg giving conversion failure when run on subclips

Tags: video, ffmpeg, extract

I have a main video clip and I am generating a subclip out of it using ffmpeg. The command i use to generate the subclip is:

```
ffmpeg -i {input_video} -ss {start_time} -to {end_time} {output_filename}
```

Once I have the subclip, I am doing the following things:

Step 1: I am calculating the average Frame Rate using ffprobe:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=avg_frame_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 <input file>
```

Step 2: I am extracting the raw video stream and storing it in a temp location and removing the existing PTS values using:

```
ffmpeg -i <input video> -c:v copy -an $TMP_STREAM 2>&1
```

Step 3: I am remuxing the video to a container forcing the average FPS causing the PTS values to be rewritten:

```
ffmpeg-r <FPS> -i $TMP_STREAM -c:v copy $OUTPUT_FILE 2>&1
```

When I do the above 3 steps on the main video clip, it works just fine. But when I do these steps on the subclip (which I generated using ffmpeg), then step 3 is giving me error:

```
Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

Any inputs on what might be happening?

Below are my commands and the logs:

Command 1:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=avg_frame_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 abcd.mp4.

---> Output: 287/12

Command 2:
ffmpeg -i abcd.mp4 -c:v copy -an /tmp/tmp.h264 2>&1

---> Output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.4 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/local/p4clients/pkgbuild-DlViY/workspace/src/FFmpeg/build/private/install --disable-static --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-encoder=vorbis --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libebur128
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'subclip_fv_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 00:00:29.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 329 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 300 kb/s, 23.92 fps, 23.92 tbr, 18368 tbn, 47.83 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 26 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File '/tmp/tmp.h264' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, h264, to '/tmp/tmp.h264':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 300 kb/s, 23.92 fps, 23.92 tbr, 23.92 tbn, 23.92 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  703 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1077kB time=00:00:29.31 bitrate= 301.1kbits/s speed=4.47e+03x
video:1077kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.010517%
```

Command 3:
ffmpeg-r 287/12 -i /tmp/tmp.h264 -c:v copy abcd.mp4_retimed.mkv 2>&1

----> Ouput:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.4 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/local/p4clients/pkgbuild-DlViY/workspace/src/FFmpeg/build/private/install --disable-static --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-encoder=vorbis --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libebur128
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, h264, from '/tmp/tmp.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 23.92 fps, 23.92 tbr, 1200k tbn, 47.83 tbc
Output #0, matroska, to 'subclip_fv_1.mp4_retimed.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 23.92 fps, 23.92 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.92 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[matroska @ 0x43d880] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[matroska @ 0x43d880] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

Comment: Need to see actual commands and logs.

Comment: @Gyan - updated the post. Thanks for your help on this :)

Answer (score 0):

The third step relies on the output muxer assigning timestamps in the absence of no input timestamps. Among the common muxers, only MP4 does this, so

```
ffmpeg-r 287/12 -i /tmp/tmp.h264 -c:v copy abcd.mp4_retimed.mp4
```

After you get that MP4, you can run

```
ffmpeg -i abcd.mp4_retimed.mp4 -c copy abcd.mp4_retimed.mkv
```